# magento 1.9.x / turpentine 0.7.10 / Varnish 4.x - block inside cms page not flushing

Tags: magento-1.9, php, varnish, turpentine

I am trying to flush a cms block I have added to a page as seen in the picture below.

[image]
[image]

Now I have put the code on the last screen inside the cms page under the "design" tab. and in the turpentine_esi.xml. None of them seem to be working.

I am flushing with a custom flush event "car_select" that is working since it flushes other references perfectly.
What am I missing, or what am I doing wrong?
If so sorry and please provide a link.

Comment: Disable varnish cache and check or do you want that cms block display without caching right?

Comment: do you see this block name in debug log?

Comment: @Nits the block/page is cached right. But when a car is selected the block should be refreshed. But it doesn't. So it doesn't whole punch.

Comment: @MagenX will check right away, good one !

Comment: @BramHammer you should set that block or call that block via xml layout and after that whole punch that block via block name. I was faced this kind of issue.

Comment: @MagenX i get the following in the log: [gist to log](https://gist.github.com/breakerh/2f990d3a78d668907f7d21d084aafef8)

Comment: @Nits i did.. [link to screenshot](http://prntscr.com/e6iq2w).. Sorry for some thing being in Dutch :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to invalidate the cache inside a cms page.
So cache entire cms block or don't cache it at all..

Answer (score 0):

Please add below code in your Page.xml or varnish layout file.

```
<cms_index_index>
    <reference name="carfitment">
        <action method="setEsiOptions">
            <params>
                <access>private</access>
                <scope>page</scope>
                <ttl>0</ttl>
            </params>
        </action>
    </reference>
</cms_index_index>
```

Add below code in cms block design and other code from it

```
<reference name="content">
    <block type="core/template" name="carfitment" as="carfitment" template="showoff/fitment/index.phtml" />
</reference>
```

Save cms page and try to refresh varnish cache.

I Hope it will help you.

Comment: Sadly enough it doesn't work :(
It does show up on [the turpentine.log](https://gist.github.com/breakerh/27af1801867b649cbf8509e56d7e3748).

Comment: Hmm okey, now i know why it showed up on the log. There was another block with the same name. I changed it to a unique name and now i get the error `" No block node found with @name="carfitment_home""`.

So it doesn't see a block inside a cms page?

Comment: Yes, Now your issue resolved?

Comment: in short, no. There is no way to invalidate the cache inside a cms page.
So will have to find some thing else for it.